# How do you set the FileTypeIndex in a DoExecute TFileSaveDialog Event if the extension is known?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

If a file extension is known how do you convert the extension to a FileTypeIndex in the TFileSaveDialog DoExecute event?

```
   function TIEWin7FileSaveDialog.DoExecute: Bool;
    begin
    ...
    {Set FileType (filter) index}
    iWideTextension := ExtractFileExt(FileName);
    FileTypeIndex := ???ExtensionToFileTypeIndex(iWideExtension);???
    FileDialog.SetFileTypeIndex(FileTypeIndex);
    ...
    end;
```

Comment: You know what extension each of your file types has. So you loop round them to find which index matches.

Comment: Ok Thanks David... I thought there may be a better way or some function do do so.

Comment: Not that I know. I do it exactly as described in that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no explicit function that would do what you want at least since one file type may be contained in more file type masks, so you can only iterate the [`FileTypes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TCustomFileDialog.FileTypes) and check if the file type is contained or equals to the [`FileMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TFileTypeItem.FileMask) like shown below:

```
function FindFirstFileType(FileDialog: TCustomFileDialog;
  const FileExt: string): UINT;
var
  TypeIndex: Integer;
  ExtIndex: Integer;
  ExtArray: TStringDynArray;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for TypeIndex := 0 to FileDialog.FileTypes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    ExtArray := SplitString(FileDialog.FileTypes[TypeIndex].FileMask, ';');
    for ExtIndex := 0 to High(ExtArray) do
      if ExtArray[ExtIndex] = FileExt then
        begin
          Result := TypeIndex;
          Break;
        end;
  end;
end;
```

And the usage (note that the input must match exactly to the filter mask):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: UINT;
begin
  I := FindFirstFileType(FileOpenDialog1, '*.pas');
end;
```